# What is 'may_terminate' in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-router

I am beginner working with Zend. I have seen `may_terminate` in module route configuration. I don't understand what it is for. According to [ZF2 official docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#treeroutestack),

```
the option “may_terminate” hints to the router that no other 
segments will follow it.
```

Still I don't get the meaning of `no other segments will follow it`. What is **`it`** here? Can anyone please explain it with small example?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `may_terminate` option will indicate to the router that 'this' route is able to be matched solely on the value of its `route`; even when it defines `child_routes`.

Consider the following example route configuration.

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [

        'home' => [
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/home',
            ],
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => [

                'foo' => [
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/foo',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

There is some ambiguity in the above configuration, which only occurs with routes that define children. Do we want to allow our users to match on two routes or just one?

We could allow matching on just the `/home` part; which would mean we have two routes both
`/home` and `/home/foo` or we might only want to allow `/home/foo`.

This is where the `may_terminate` option is used. If we browsed to `/home` in our browser, when the routing occurs the router **cannot** regard the `home` route as a matchable route as `may_terminate = false`. In ZF2 terminology the router cannot *"terminate"* at this route and continues on searching for a match into the `child_routes`, which will fail and a 404 error will be raised.

So by modifying the value of the `may_terminate` option in the above example, we can change the routes that can be matched on.

`may_terminate = true`

- home
- home/foo

`may_terminate = false`

- home/foo

Comment: Just a question: Is the definition of the "foo" route wrong? In my option it should be just "foo" instead of "/foo". Else you will have a double slash. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @Stillmatic1985 I does seem that way at first glance, I didn't check my config but did see [this example](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-part) in the docs

Comment: Hmm ok. Didnt tested it but it looks wrong. if you had "/home" as home route everything looks great but i think if you only have "/" as home route the child route shouldnt have a starting slash. I could be wrong. ;)

Comment: @Stillmatic1985 you are right. The example is read a bit tricky... It's the factory creating and actually the first child_routes doesn't belong to the home route at all. Look closely ;) Didn't really look at the code too closely, good catch

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to find out what I was doing wrong.