# Zend framework edit a record

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-router

I am trying to create edit records functionality in my listing page. But i am getting following error when clicking on edit link against record.

A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available

My module.config.php file code for edit view is :

```
'edit' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                         'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'edit',
                     ),
            ),
        ),
```

And my Album listing page code for calling edit controller and passing id to is :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('edit',
             array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => $album->id));?>">Edit</a>
```

and editAction code is :

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
```

Please let me know what i m missing. I am new to zend framework.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use `'type' => 'segment'` have a look on the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment)

```
<?php
'edit' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment', /* <--- use segment*/
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Album',
            'action'     => 'edit',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Yes i tried to put 'type' => 'segment' but still it is not working even after putting 'type' => 'segment' page not responding...

Answer (score 0):

Advise regarding the `type` option is correct, however you will also need the [`may_terminate` option to ensure that the router knows that this route can be matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785532/what-is-may-terminate-in-zend-framework-2/20786800#20786800).

```
 'edit' => array(
        'type' => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                 'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Album',
                 'action'     => 'edit',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true, // Add this line
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

See now my route script in module.config.php is this.

```
'album' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Album',
                    'action'        => 'album',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                 'add' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album/[:add]',
                'constraints' => array(
                                'add' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                            ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Album',
                    'action'        => 'add',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'edit' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album/[:edit][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                                'edit' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
                            ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Album',
                    'action'        => 'edit',
                ),
            ),
        ),
),
    ),
```

in this case if i am clicking on any link only the album page displaying not other which i am hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution and now my application is working perfectly....
I just replace above code with :

```
'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'album',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
```