# Zend 2 Navigation rendering active class missing

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

i do have a problem regarding rendering the navigation in zf2. I have not found anybody else having this issue. But maybe you have a clue.

Althought everything seems to be configured right, due to the fact that everything does work, rendering zend navigation does not mark the active route with class="active".

This is part of my module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'app_navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'User\Acl\Service' => 'User\Acl\ServiceFactory',
            'User\Auth\Service' => 'User\Authentication\ServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),

//global config key for all navigation configurations
'navigation' => array(
     //name of the DefaultNavigation created by DefaultNavigationFactory
     'default' => array(
         //config of first page
         'welcome' => array(
             'label' => 'Home',
             'route' => 'welcome',
             'controller' => 'People\Controller\PeopleController',
             'action' => 'welcome',
             'type' => 'uri',
             'uri' => '/welcome',
             'module'    => 'TheGlobalDatabase',
         ),
...
```

This is the route:

```
     'router' => array(       
        'routes' => array(
           'welcome' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/welcome',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'People\Controller\People',
                        'action'     => 'welcome',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

I do echo the navigation in the layout like this:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu('app_navigation',array('ulClass'=>'nav navbar-nav welcome'));
```

Maybe you have a hint, what else to check.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing or incorrect config in both route and navigation.

**Navigation**

- You will never need to use the `type` param when using array config. It is the navigation factory's job to determine if the type is either `uri` or `mvc`. Just remove the config for it.
- The navigation `controller` Should be the registered service name of the controller, not the fully qualified class name. `'controller' => 'People\Controller\People'`.
- Also [You do not need to specify the `controller` and `action` in the navigation config](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.pages.html#using-routes) when using a route param.

With these changes, the navigation is very simple.

```
 'welcome' => array(
   'label' => 'Home',
   'route' => 'welcome'
 );
```

**Route**

It could be a `Literal` route (as there are no parameters being passed in) and you are missing the `may_terminate` argument [which will be required if you wish to match on your route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785532/what-is-may-terminate-in-zend-framework-2).

```
'welcome' => array(
    'type'    => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/welcome',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'People\Controller\People',
            'action'     => 'welcome',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
),
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much! Cleaning up did help immediately!