# ZF2 Controller mapping issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules, zend-framework-routing

I am new to Zend.
I have set up local dev at `zend.local`
I am creating a new module say **Csv**, when I go to URL like zend.local/csv, it gives me the following error
[image]

My `module.config.php` is below:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Csv\Controller\Csv' => 'Csv\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'csv' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/csv[/][:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Csv\Controller\IndexController',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'csv' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have provided the wrong controller name :

```
             'defaults' => array(
                 'controller' => 'Csv\Controller\IndexController',
                 'action'     => 'index',
             ),
```

it should be

```
             'defaults' => array(
                 'controller' => 'Csv\Controller\Csv',
                 'action'     => 'index',
             ),
```

according to your config

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Csv\Controller\Csv' => 'Csv\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

You require the [`may_terminate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785532/what-is-may-terminate-in-zend-framework-2) option to ensure the router can regard `csv` as a route that it can *terminate* at.

```
'csv' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/csv[/][:action][/:id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Csv\Controller\IndexController',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true // added
),
```

Comment: `may_terminate` is only required when there is a sub route